# How to print a min and max values based on a condition - dplyR

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
> df <- data_frame(g = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'), x = c(7, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4))
> df
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

  g x
1 A 7
2 A 3
3 B 5
4 B 9
5 B 2
6 A 4
```

I want to print min value for A group and maximum value for B group
output

```
  g x
1 A 3
2 B 9
```

Comment: Similar to below attempts, you can also do : `df %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(x = if(first(g) == 'A') min(x) else max(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% group_by(g) %>% 
  mutate(x=ifelse(g=='A',min(x,na.rm = T),
                     ifelse(g=='B',max(x,na.rm = T)))) %>%
  summarise(x=unique(x))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  g         x
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         3
2 B         9
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. What if I have to group by two columns instead? Also, I want to keep all other columns in the output if there are any.

Comment: @user14361718 Hi dear. In that case you could do `df %>% group_by(col1,col2) %>% mutate(Newvar='...)` if you want to keep the other columns you should use mutate and compute your variables. Hope that helped and let me know if that was clear enough!

Answer (score 2):

Another option

```r
df %>% group_by(g) %>% summarise(x = unique(ifelse(g == "A", min(x), max(x))))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   g         x
#>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 A         3
#> 2 B         9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, .(x = unique(fifelse(g == "A", min(x), max(x)))), .(g)]
```